# How to filter in mongoDB in node to get entire object when you search for a title in the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to make a filter that allows you to search for the title or in my case(recipeName) but send along everything inside that object. Like If i search for fruit sallad i also want to retrive the description, image, category etc. Its for a project in school and im kind of lost how to proceed espcially with the arrays any help would be nice

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR1bG.jpg "MongoDb Structure"

Comment: Please don't link to images of code. Show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular querying with MongoDB should return the whole object, such as doing a findOne query on a document `e.g. yourcollectionname.findOne({recipeName: 'Oreo Pudding'})`

If you're using the MongoDB driver, the findOne query takes an object as the first argument with the query options, and a callback as the second argument `e.g. yourcollectionname.findOne({recipeName: 'Oreo Pudding'}, (err, doc) => { // do something with the error and the document object here})`

Answer (score 0):

You did not offer any code on your collection or model you are trying to query so lets go with `User`. If you are to use `User.findOne()` you also need a `.then()`. So `User` is the collection, `findOne()` is the type of query where an query is an operation to look through all the records in a database, but if you just implement `User.findOne()` without chaining on the `.then()`, nothing would actually be issued to your database.

When you just call `findOne()` that returns what is called a query. It does not actually go off to your database automatically. Its only when you say `.then()` that the query actually gets executed.

You may still see some slightly different documentation around `mongoose` which uses `.exec()`, short for execute. Thats for use with the older legacy callback type syntax, whereas the assumption here is that we are using promises. With promises you use `.then()`.